# Flutter Cloud Messaging not showing Message info in foreground

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging in my Flutter project.

I have already created a project in Firebase and setup my Flutter project to use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Here you have the main.dart code:

```
import 'package:fcm_flutter/push_notification.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:overlay_support/overlay_support.dart';


import 'notification_badge.dart';

Future _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
  FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter FCM',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter FCM'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late int _totalNotifications;
  PushNotification? _notificationInfo;

  late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _totalNotifications = 0;
    registerNotification();
    // Call here
    checkForInitialMessage();

    // For handling notification when the app is in background
    // but not terminated
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
        title: message.notification?.title,
        body: message.notification?.body,
      );
      setState(() {
        _notificationInfo = notification;
        _totalNotifications++;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  void registerNotification() async {
    // 1. Initialize the Firebase app
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    // 2. Instantiate Firebase Messaging
    _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    // 3. On iOS, this helps to take the user permissions
    NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
      // TODO: handle the received notifications
      // For handling the received notifications
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        // Parse the message received
        PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
          title: message.notification?.title,
          body: message.notification?.body,
        );

        setState(() {
          _notificationInfo = notification;
          _totalNotifications++;
        });
      });
      if (_notificationInfo != null) {
        // For displaying the notification as an overlay
        showSimpleNotification(
          Text(_notificationInfo!.title!),
          leading: NotificationBadge(totalNotifications: _totalNotifications),
          subtitle: Text(_notificationInfo!.body!),
          background: Colors.cyan.shade700,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        );
      }
    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
  }

  // For handling notification when the app is in terminated state
  checkForInitialMessage() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
      PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
        title: initialMessage.notification?.title,
        body: initialMessage.notification?.body,
      );
      setState(() {
        _notificationInfo = notification;
        _totalNotifications++;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'App for capturing Firebase Push Notifications',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          NotificationBadge(totalNotifications: _totalNotifications),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          // TODO: add the notification text here
          _notificationInfo != null
              ? Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'TITLE: ${_notificationInfo!.title}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                    Text(
                      'BODY: ${_notificationInfo!.body}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here you have the packages installed in pubspec.yaml:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: "^1.2.1"
  firebase_messaging: "^10.0.1"
  overlay_support: ^1.2.1
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.6
```

I am sending a message using Cloud Messaging console and I am only getting this output in Android Studio Console:

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 5486): broadcast received for message
```

but any message in the app:

[image]

What am I missing to get the message data when the app is in foreground.

When the app is active but in background, it is launching the push notification.

When the app is not closed, it is launching the push notification.

EDIT:

Message sent:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to listen on a message, add the following line:

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

And the problem would be solved.

To be honest, I don't understand why it works but I will look more into it in the future Insha'Allah.

Comment: It works because you need a permission for sending push notification and when you ask to get the device token with getToken() method your device ask for a user permission.

Answer (score 1):

Messages that only have a notification key are handled by the system and not delivered to your application. This means that in order for a message to be deliver to your application code while the app is active, the message will need to contain a data key.

For more on this, see the Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: I am putting always a data key and value when sending the message, key: click_action, value: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK

Comment: You might want to show the message you send in your question.

Comment: Done, you may see the message in my question